# C# FFmpeg Dynamic-Link Library

Tags: c#, dll, ffmpeg

I need FFmpeg as dll for C#. I want to do something like;

```cs
static void Convert(Stream onlyAudioStream, Stream onlyVideoStream, string path)
{
    FFmpegNameSpace.FFmpeg ff = new FFmpegNameSpace.FFmpeg();
    ff.AddInput(onlyAudioStream);
    ff.AddInput(onlyVideoStream);
    ff.Save(path);
}
```

And the problem is I don't know how can i get ffmpeg dll.

Example:
I did this before in libwebp. Things we need to do to get libwebp dll;
1- Download libwebp source
2- Open Visual Studio 2019 Developer Tools
3- Run command in libwebp source directory "nmake /f Makefile.vc CFG=release-static RTLIBCFG=static OBJDIR=output"
4- Done you will find dll in output directory

Edit: I searched a lot and couldn't find the solution. I decided to use ffmpeg.exe whenever I need it.
Thank you all

Comment: Is there any reason not to use a package like FFmpeg.NET?

Comment: FFmpeg.NET too creates ffmpeg.exe. It's just wrapper.

Comment: Try `FFmpeg.AutoGen` (native wrapper) and `libav` (dll)